# Ruby method doesn't seem to return value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby (and Rails), and I'm trying to take the form data from the view file and calculate something in the controller, but no value seems to be returned by the method. I have a feeling it's something very simple that I'm overlooking.

This is inside a `def create`:

```
    def calcQuadrant

        important = params[:task][:important] # INT of 0 or 1
        urgent = params[:task][:urgent] # INT of 0 or 1

        if important == 1 && urgent == 1
            return 1
        elsif important == 1 && urgent == 0
            return 2
        elsif important == 0 && urgent == 1
            return 3
        elsif important == 0 && urgent == 0
            return 4
        end
    end
```

`calcQuadrant` doesn't seem return anything, even when I `put` `important` or `urgent` to the console and they have values. I'm ultimately trying to assign the value returned by `calcQuadrant` to a new param: `params[:task][:quadrant]`.

At a high level, what I'm really trying to figure out is the best way for passing a param to the model which wasn't passed to the controller from the view. Is the best way to do that just assigning a value to that param in the controller? For example, I ask the user for a 'to-do' and whether the to-do is 'important' and/or 'urgent'. Based on their choices, I calculate a quadrant for the task to go into. Rather than saving the importance and urgency of the to-do in the DB, I just want to save the quadrant.

Comment: why don't you map it via routes? i.e. post: /todo/:id/important

Answer (score 1):

Probably `params[:task][:important]` and `params[:task][:urgent]` are strings not integer. Check this.

I've tried this and the result is 2 as expected.

```
 def calcQuadrant
    important = 1
    urgent = 0

    if important == 1 && urgent == 1
        1
    elsif important == 1 && urgent == 0
        2
    elsif important == 0 && urgent == 1
        3
    elsif important == 0 && urgent == 0
        4
    end
end
```

Comment: Wow. Like I said, something simple I was overlooking. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your code will obviously not return what you expect if somehow the `important` or `urgent` variables contain, for example, `2`, or, `nil`, or, as the other answer points out, the string `"1"`.

You should constrain the variables `important` and `urgent` to be boolean, for example:

```
def calcQuadrant

    important = params[:task][:important].to_i == 1
    urgent = params[:task][:urgent].to_i == 1

    if important && urgent
        1
    elsif important && !urgent
        2
    elsif !important && urgent
        3
    elsif !important && !urgent
        4
    end
end
```

And finally, remember that in Ruby, the last expression evaluated in a function becomes the return value of the function, so in your example you don't need the `return` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

`params` integer values are received as strings, do this, use `to_i` method

```
important = params[:task][:important].to_i
urgent = params[:task][:urgent].to_i
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a much shorter version :

```
def calc_quadrant
  important = params[:task][:important].to_i
  urgent    = params[:task][:urgent].to_i

  4 - 2*important - urgent
end
```

For your second question. Controllers should be skinny, Models are allowed to be fat. The quadrant logic should be inside the Model.

You don't have to save everything you define in the Model into the database. Feel free to show your model definition if you want more info.